# keeping everything in one line in div

Tags: css

so my problem is like this:

I have a div, and in the div I have an img and then a string next to the image, the height is at 25, the width is at 128, and its align to center.

its just a username and a little icon next to their name.  it works fine up until the user has a really long name in which case it will put the string onto a new line, which is definitely not what I want.

I would like it to just over flow and hide the rest of the name if it is too long.  is there anyway I can do this?

I had overflow hidden as well as max-height and max-width.  I tried using a span as well as display:inline but it keeps pushing it to a new line. I need to keep the alignment centered.

any help?

cant seem to find any information.  I tried putting it in a table as well but to no avail.

here's the code:

```
<a href="#" class="tab2">        
    <table  align="center">            
        <tr>                
            <td valign="bottom"  id="contactLink1">    
                <div align="center" class="funtion_user_imageloc_box">
                    <?php if($memimglevelROW['imageloc']!=''){
                        if ($memimglevelROW['imageloc']=="black1.png"){?>
                            <img src="levelimage/<?php echo $memimglevelROW['imageloc'];?>"  alt="" width="30.5" height="16" align="center" class="funtion_user_img1" />&nbsp;    
                        <?php } else {?>
                            <img src="levelimage/<?php echo $memimglevelROW['imageloc'];?>" alt="" width="18" height="18" align="center" class="funtion_user_img2" />&nbsp;    
                        <?php }            
                    }
                    echo $username;?>
                </div>
            </td>        
        </tr>    
    </table>
</a>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Welcome to the community!

- Please try not to post a wall of text, as it makes reading your question difficult.
- The preview of what you're typing is below the "Ask a Question" textbox.
- Thanks for providing code!

You should try `white-space: nowrap;` as that will probably fix your problem.

Also, **don't ever use tables for non-tabular data**. It's not 1995 anymore, CSS can do anything a table can do.

Comment: I'll agree with most of what Bov says [came here to post white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden], but there are times where a 30 second table is far better than 4 hours of futzing with divs and css.  Time is money :)

Comment: @Sean, Not to be condescending, but I've *never* spent four hours fussing over a style that replaces a table. Vertical-centering and automatic horizontal alignment are much easier than many designers seem to realize.

Comment: I have -- just this weekend in fact.  Not to get too far OT, but the CSS to get something "simple" like a fluid three column layout has been discussed for years (especially when dealing with all the browser issues) with no consensus "best practice".  A table, in three cells solves this immediately.  Although it does, obviously make it much, much harder to change the layout in the future.  If you have to support IE7 or heaven forbid IE6, then you tend to "futz" a lot unfortunately.

Comment: @Sean, `display: table-row; display: table-cell`, or `display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;`, or `float: left; width: 33%` will all get you fluid 3-column layouts.

Comment: with a footer, differing length columns? This is a typical problem that doesn't have a simple answer. three column layout css in google gives 137,000 results.  And I'd contend that the extra container divs being injected into the markup to support most of these techniques are no better than a single row table with TDs when it comes to maintainability (when you go to relayout the site, you're going to touch the markup either way).

Comment: @Sean, shoot me an e-mail and we can discuss this more there if you'd like.